# Could not find matching close tag for "<%", how can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, express, tags, ejs

This is the problematic part:

```
<% for(var j = 0;j < <%= items %>.length; j++){ %>
<li><%= items[j] %></li>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the reason for this could be that you have inserted the "<%" tag inside another one.

Can you please try to rewrite the code like this?

```
<% for(var j = 0;j < items.length; j++){ %>
<li><%= items[j] %></li>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to tell what you are trying to do here, but the root cause is that you **cannot nest** sets of `<% ... %>`.

Probably you just want:

```
<% for (var j=0; j < items.length; j++) { %>
    <li><%= items[j] %></li>
<% } %>
```

Possibly you expect `items` to be provided by *client-side* JavaScript and not EJS, in which case see [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your code as below, you don't need to use the `<%= %>` with items.

```
<% for(var j = 0;j < items.length; j++){ %>
   <li><%= items[j] %></li>
<%}%>
```